# CSS3 box-shadow + inset + RGBA

Tags: standards, w3c, css

I'm doing some tests with new features of CSS3, but this combination only works in lastest versions of Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari or Opera:

```
box-shadow:         inset 0px -10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px -10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

I really don't know if they fails in the box-shadow itself, in the inset parameter, or in RGBA color. It's a syntax error or simply Safari and Opera lacks on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inset` keyword is not supported in Safari 4, but is supported in Safari 5 and Opera 10.5. Check that you're using the latest versions of each.

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-box-shadow#Browser_compatibility
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-border-background-boxshadow/#box-shadow

Comment: Wow, I thought Safari was more updated... but is not a great loss, Safari does not run into my GNU/Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

This might help the web programmers: [opera box-shadow bug](http://templatereactor.com/blog/opera-box-shadow-bug.html) , but hopefully the browser developers will notice it too and fix this tiny but unpleasant issue.