# Set a inset box shadow in css3

Tags: css, shadow, insets

I use css3 in my web projects but i don't know how to set a inset little shadow on the top of the box ?  I tried to set this following code for ex :

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px #fff
```

Thanks

Comment: What browser have you tested? Do you have a background? Have you [looked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490029/css3-box-shadow-inset-rgba?rq=1) [at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400130/why-does-a-background-break-a-box-shadow-inset-effect?rq=1) related questions?

Comment: Is it possible that the background of your element is white and therefore you do not see the shadow?

Comment: please provide `jsfiddle` , your code seems be ok

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 10px -2px #FFF;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vj6sD/1/)